# Date of Monday of a given week, independent of NLS

Tags: oracle

I have an input date (say sysdate) and I want to get the date of the previous Monday. I tried

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'D') from dual;
```

but it is NLS dependent. Also I don't want to go around with checking the result by name because it may vary depending on the language of the country that my code will run on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use ISO weeks

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'IW') - 7 previous_monday FROM dual
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14185)** demo